# Why does "arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion” Remove the Target Feature Class from the ArcMap Project TOC (Arc 10.2.2)?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have a script that successfully converts CSVs to Feature Classes.  The only problem is that the final line is causing my target feature class to be removed from the Table of Contents in the .mxd.

Code Snippet:

```
import arcpy
Source_CSV = r"\\int.ec\Data\Stations.csv"
Target_FC = r"Q:\Data\Stations.gdb\Stations"
Description = arcpy.Describe(Target_FC)
Target_FC_name = Description.name
Target_GDB = os.path.split(Description.catalogPath) [0]
Temp_Layer = "Temp_Layer"
SR = arcpy.Describe(Target_FC).spatialReference
Field_Mapping = """Muni "Muni" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,Muni,-1,-1;LSName "LSName" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,LSName,-1,-1;Lat "Lat" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,Lat,-1,-1;Lng "Lng" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,Lng,-1,-1;PercFlow "PercFlow" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,PercFlow,-1,-1;OutLat "OutLat" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,OutLat,-1,-1;OutLng "OutLng" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,OutLng,-1,-1;AlarmSystemType "AlarmSystemType" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,AlarmSystemType,-1,-1;CanOverFlow "CanOverFlow" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,CanOverFlow,-1,-1;Address "Address" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,Address,-1,-1;CSSPUrl "CSSPUrl" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,CSSPUrl,-1,-1;Comment "Comment" true true false 8000 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Temp_Layer,Comment,-1,-1"""
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Source_CSV, "Lng", "Lat", Temp_Layer, SR, "")
arcpy.AddMessage('Beginning Feature Class to Feature Class conversion...') 
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Temp_Layer, Target_GDB, Target_FC_name, "", Field_Mapping)
```

I'm quite sure the problem is with the last line because when the print statement just before it prints my target FC is still there.  Seconds later I see it disappear from the TOC and the script ends successfully.

Here are my parameters.  Though you can't see it here the 2nd one is set to "Direction: Input".  Don't worry about the 3rd parameter, it's just used (successfully) in the validation script to auto-populate certain fields and variables.

[image]

The 4th parameter I recently added at the suggestion of MichaelStimson, but obviously I misunderstood something because now I get the following error:

```
ERROR 000733
New Feature Class: Same as input
```

I have since removed the 4th parameter.

Again, there's no problem with the execution of the script per se, I just want to know how to prevent my target FC from being removed from the map project.  Ideas?

Comment: In your tool dialog what is your output data type? Is it file, feature class or layer? Have you got a line with arcpy.SetParameter http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SetParameter/03q300000055000000/? It sounds like your output is temporary so it's only added to the TOC while you're in the script and then removed as soon as the script finishes. Specifying the output as a parameter and then using SetParameter (SetParameterAsText) should make the result permanent.

Comment: Is this a full on tool, like Michael suggests, or are you just running a script in the python window?  If its just a Python script, change FC2FC for CopyFeatures. It does the same thing, unless you absolutely need the field mapping.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - ah, so unless I have a parameter set to "Direction: Output" Arc will remove the final product from the TOC?  My second parameter, "Target Feature Class", is set to "Direction: Input".  But since my application of FC2FC overwrites the Target Feature Class, as desired, I suppose I have to add another parameter, also called "Target Feature Class", and set it to "Direction: Output"?  Seems a bit redundant but perhaps that is the fix?

Comment: @KHibma - My version of Arc (10.2.2) limits FC2FC to 256 characters / field so I need the field mapping to force it to the proper 8000 characters for a feature class within a gdb.  I could try CopyFeatures but fear there is a good chance it will also limit me to 256 characters in Arc 10.2.2?

Comment: It sounds like that could be the culprit, set the direction to output and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - I'm not understanding how to treat a parameter that I want as my input but also apparently I have to set it as my output (in order to keep it in the TOC after the tool runs).  I've edited my original question to hopefully give you more to work on, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - I've also tried it without the 4th parameter and just making the 2nd parameter set to Direction:Output, but then the tool just deletes the feature class altogether with no new product to take its place.

Comment: That is a little bit of a quandary, the tool validator is being a bit arbitrary with its rules.. Because you want to specify a feature class that already exists your parameter should be input but you can't have the same value for an input and an output. Perhaps try adding the layer to your map arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer(os.path.join(Target_GDB, Target_FC_name),'YourLayer') arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT'))[0],'YourLayer')

Comment: I suggest putting your tool aside for now, taking your "final line" out into a new script and seeing how much more code you need to add into it before you have created a minimum length [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that illustrates precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.  The code ideas suggested by @MichaelStimson look like they should be part of that snippet.

Comment: @PolyGeo - I'm quite certain there's nothing in my preceding script that has anything to do with the issue of "FC2FC_conversion()" removing my target feature class.  Nonetheless, as requested I have added it in a code snippet.  I tried the suggestion by Michael Stimson to re-add the layer but am getting other errors related to that now, and besides, the point of my question is to find out how I can make "FC2FC_conversion()" NOT remove the target FC from the TOC.

Comment: A code snippet for this would import arcpy, FCtoFC a test feature class, MakeFeatureLayer from the output and may or may not need to AddLayer it (I can't remember).  With that 4 or so line script added behind a tool dialog with no parameters I would feel that I was ready to commence testing and start reporting what was not behaving as expected.

Comment: W.r.t. "the point of my question is to find out how I can make "FC2FC_conversion()" NOT remove the target FC from the TOC", I don't believe you can prevent it being removed from the Contents window but you should be able to put it back

Comment: @PolyGeo - So technically the answer to my question is... "It just does, and there's no way you can stop it."?

Comment: Self-answering is permissible. I've not tested in this instance and so would not go as far as to answer that definitively at this point.

Comment: OK, I'll give it some time before self-answering.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a code snippet we are left to guess what may be causing this but my suspicion is that you have:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

which causes the data source for that layer to be deleted as part of the overwrite (which removes it from the Contents window), and you have not written any code to add the replacement data as a new layer.